# Replacing texts with emoticons in JavaScript from Json values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to replace text with images.For example, abc:) should be converted into abc(and the respective emoticon).And I am using contenteditable element for doing the same.But, nothing seems to work.I tried using the replace() and html() functions but they don't work.

The link to my Codepen is: [Link](https://codepen.io/asinha/pen/gWoRoK)

And I don't want to use regex as I have to do more additions in my json file.Thanks!

HTML Code:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id='text-box'>  
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
document.body.onkeyup=function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==32){
                var contenteditable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]'),
                text = contenteditable.textContent;
                var word=getWord(text);
                console.log(word);
                console.log(data.value);
                if(word.includes(data.value)){
                    //alert("true");
                    var img=new Image();
                    img.src=data.image;
                    img.setAttribute("class","image");
                    //$("#text-box").append(img);
                    $("#text-box").html(function (_, html) {
     return html.replace(data.value , img );

                }       
                //$("#text-box").html(text.replace(data.value,img));
            }
        }

        function getWord(text){
            var word=text.split(" ").pop();
            return word;
        }
```

JSON data:

```
var data={
    "value":":)",
    "image":"persons-0016_large.png"
};
```

After the execution of my code,I get the output as `abc[object HTMLImageElement]` instead of the image itself.

Comment: A good first step is to make sure the syntax is valid.  For instance, closing any open `<div>` tags and making sure all open javascript parentheses have a matching closed parenthesis.

Comment: it is valid@mgamba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating an image object, replace the text by image tag like this.

```
var data={
    "value":":)",
    "image":"persons-0016_large.png"
};


document.body.onkeyup=function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==32){
        var contenteditable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]');
        var text = contenteditable.textContent;
        var word=getWord(text);
        console.log(word);
        console.log(data.value);
        if(word.includes(data.value)){
            //alert("true");
            //var img=new Image();
            //img.src=data.image;
            //img.setAttribute("class","image");

            var img = "<img src='" + img.src +"' class='image' /> ";
            //$("#text-box").append(img);
            $("#text-box").html(function (_, html) {
                return html.replace(data.value , img );
            } );      
        //$("#text-box").html(text.replace(data.value,img));
        }
    };

};

function getWord(text){
    var word=text.split(" ").pop();
    return word;
}
```

Comment: It works! Just the image is getting corrupted.Any idea why? and also how do I set the cursor to point after the image. Thanks